# Exact Ascii codes matched by Lua patterns

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns, character-class

I am translating a project from Lua to C++. In the Lua version, I use Lua's regular expressions, but for a purpose so simple that in C++ I could do it by simply comparing the characters against some Ascii codes.

To do that, however, I need the exact ascii code which each [character class](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1) matches.

As an example, `%s` matches all space characters, but what exactly are those characters? I need to know it for every Lua character class.

Comment: *I need to know it for every Lua character class.* You can bruteforce each by creating a program that enumerate each ascii  character and see what match what

Comment: [`case 'a' : res = isalpha(c); break;
    case 'c' : res = iscntrl(c); break;
    case 'd' : res = isdigit(c); break;
    case 'g' : res = isgraph(c); break;
    case 'l' : res = islower(c); break;
    case 'p' : res = ispunct(c); break;
    case 's' : res = isspace(c); break;
    case 'u' : res = isupper(c); break;
    case 'w' : res = isalnum(c); break;
    case 'x' : res = isxdigit(c); break;`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstrlib.c.html), and then see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew wasn't aware of the existance of that header. Going to use that. Thank you.

Comment: [Full list](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/98fa4afda5a157904522a52dc442440b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a peek at the [Lua source](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstrlib.c.html):

```
case 'a' : res = isalpha(c); break;
case 'c' : res = iscntrl(c); break;
case 'd' : res = isdigit(c); break;
case 'g' : res = isgraph(c); break;
case 'l' : res = islower(c); break;
case 'p' : res = ispunct(c); break;
case 's' : res = isspace(c); break;
case 'u' : res = isupper(c); break;
case 'w' : res = isalnum(c); break;
case 'x' : res = isxdigit(c); break;
case 'z' : res = (c == 0); break;  /* deprecated option */
```

You can see that there are analogous methods in [C++ `<cctype> (ctype.h)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/):

```
isalnum     Check if character is alphanumeric (function )
isalpha     Check if character is alphabetic (function )
isblank     Check if character is blank (function )
iscntrl     Check if character is a control character (function )
isdigit     Check if character is decimal digit (function )
isgraph     Check if character has graphical representation (function )
islower     Check if character is lowercase letter (function )
isprint     Check if character is printable (function )
ispunct     Check if character is a punctuation character (function )
isspace     Check if character is a white-space (function )
isupper     Check if character is uppercase letter (function )
isxdigit    Check if character is hexadecimal digit (function )
```

There are also corresponding ASCII value ranges on that page.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<cctype>` (without .h)? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just copied the name with the extension from the documentation page. Let me change it to the way it appears in the title.